# Protocol/Schema Standard for RESTFul services?

Tags: rest, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api, standards, api-design

Is there a general standard (in development) towards RESTful services? Since it's HTTP, I'm not talking about the technical standard ofcourse, but a more common way of exposing methods and functionality and implementing those.

And if not, are there general rules, to follow when developing a RESTFul service?

Or should we base ourselves on general API design, where there's already tons of books written about. Only question then to bear in mind, does it always translate to the web as well.

Comment: I did found a "lessons learned" article: https://restful-api-design.readthedocs.org/en/latest/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no standard for RESTful design.  It is simply a style.  Following the constraints of the style allows many different valid design approaches.

You cannot translate many general procedural API design guidelines into web API design because distributed computing has many different issues than library level APIs.

Comment: and there's no general rules or best practices to keep in mind when designing them?

Comment: @YvesSchelpe  Sure, but that's a book not a SO answer.  Although you will find lots of SO answers that give you partial answers.

Comment: Ok, I understand that indeed. I'll research for books then. Better this answer, then one that is partial. Thus the +1 upvote ;)!